# JAAS and JBOSS 5 problem with principal

Tags: authentication, jboss, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x, jaas

I am working with a piece of code implementing JAAS LoginModule and in the commit method I set the principal with user UUID:

```
subject.getPrincipals().add(new SimplePrincipal(userUUID)
```

But for some reason when I access the user from EJB Context:

```
context.getCallerPrincipal().getName()
```

I receive the login name of the user instead of the userUUID I was expecting.

Should I implement custom principal or how to solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be a JBoss 5 bug after all:
https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/EJBTHREE-1756

Fixed 11. Feb 2010, now waiting a next JBoss release :-)

Answer (score 1):

The following workaround seems to work:

1. Get a copy of JBoss 6.0.0.Final
2. Copy the file $JBOSS_HOME/common/lib/jboss-ejb3-security.jar to the JBoss 5.1 installation directory.
3. Restart JBoss